# Navigate to another view controller from a popup view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a table in my pop up view. But when clicking on a table row, it doesn't navigate to another view controller. Is there any direct method to navigate from popup view to another view controller ?

thanks in advance.

Code::

```
ProductListView1 *p = [[ProductListView1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductListView1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:p animated:YES];
```

Comment: Post your code which you have did for navigation to another viewController.....

Comment: ok, I am adding my code.

Comment: what happens while using this code????

Comment: is there any crash or anything else?????

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or just nibs?

Comment: no, I am not using story board. And it does noting. no crash.

Comment: ProductListView1 *p = [[ProductListView1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductListView1" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 1):

ContentViewController of popover, should be a navigation controller.

First create navigationController with rootViewController as tableViewController(first controller to be displayed in popover)

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
```

and then present navigationController in popover

```
[popOver setContentViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

And then you can push another controller in tableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method

```
ProductListView1 *p = [[ProductListView1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductListView1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:p animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `[self presentViewController:p animated:YES completion:nil];`

If you don't have a `UINavigationController` than you can't push a `UIViewController`.

Also note, that if you push a `UIViewController` in a `UIPopoverController`, it will just enlarge the UIPopover. If you want a whole new view to be displayed, than you must use `presentViewController:` and you could put a UIToolbar to a UINavigationController onto that modal view.